Is there a way to generate p2 director decision tree?
On Eclipse, when I export a product, an update site is created, then the p2 director creates an installation.  Is there a way to log a "decision tree" that shows what causes the inclusion of each of my plugins?
I'm asking this because there's an Eclipse plugin being included on our product and I don't know why.  I'd like to understand the dependency chain that leads to its inclusion.

In Eclipse, in the Features view you can enable Show Workspace Products and Show Included Plugins and Fragments to have a tree with the product as root node with features and plugins/fragments as sub-nodes. And in the Plug-in Dependencies view, you could start from the plugin and use Show Callers. In the update site, the content.xml which is zipped in the content.jar contains what is required by what. Instead of looking into content.xml manually, you can use the Oomph Repository Explorer.

The Repository Explorer view is part of Oomph Targlets which can be installed e.g. from the update site https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest.

Thanks, @howlger.  I'll check those.
